# How to separate a integral values

Tags: python

I have a dataframe in the following form:

`a=[(0.0,),(40.0,),(40.0,),(40.0,)]`

How do I get the integral values from this data (i.e I want to get the following output):

```
a=[0,40,40,40]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [1]: a=[(0.0,),(40.0,),(40.0,),(40.0,)]

In [2]: b = [int(i[0]) for i in a]

In [3]: b
Out[3]: [0, 40, 40, 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to achieve the objective

```
# for python3
a=[(0.0,),(40.0,),(40.0,),(40.0,)]

y=[]
for x in a:
  y.append(int(x[0]))

print (y)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 40, 40, 40]
```